# Ошибка компиляции кода из книги Р.Лафоре

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Учу язык С++ по книги **Р.Лафоре "Объектно-ориентированное программирование на С++"**.
Часто замечал, что некоторый код, который написан в книге, не компилируется в **Visual Studio 17** (как с другими версиями - не знаю).

Например, при компиляции следующий код

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

class ClassString
{
private:
    char *str;
public:
    ClassString(char *s)
    {
        int len = strlen(s);
        str = new char[len + 1];
        strcpy(str, s);
    }
    ~ClassString()
    {
        cout << "Удаляю строку" << endl;
        delete[] str;
    }

    void display()
    {
        cout << "str: " << str << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    ClassString someObj = "someString";
    cout << "someObj = ";
    someObj.display();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

просто не компилируется, вызывая следующие ошибки:

1. > E0415  не существует подходящего конструктора для преобразования из "const char [11]" в "ClassString**"
2. > C4996  'strcpy': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using strcpy_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.**
3. > C2440  инициализация: невозможно преобразовать "const char [11]" в "ClassString"**

Код скопирован полностью слово в слово, изменены лишь название переменных. Неужели автор книги схалтурил? Или проблемы выражены у меня? Ведь точно такой же код без проблем компилируется в онлайн-компиляторах.

**Каким образом мне поступить, чтобы решить эту проблему, в частности: что нужно сделать, чтобы код, который я написал, компилировался верно, согласно книги?**

Comment: для какой версии c++ дан пример в книге?

Comment: Кстати если речь идет об издании 2004 года, то имеет смысл почитать что-то другое, книга очень сильно отстала от реалий C++: 15 лет и три новых редакции языка.

Comment: Книга издания 2017 года. В описании написано, что весь код был протестирован на компиляторе MVC++ 6.0. Согласен, действительно старый компилятор.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, этот код является нерабочим. Строковый литерал является массивом `char const` и его нельзя передать в функцию, принимающую указатель на `char` (не `const`). Чтобы исправить достаточно дописать:

```
ClassString(char const * s)
```

а еще лучше сделать и сам указатель константным - ведь внутри конструктора он не меняется:

```
ClassString(char const * const s)
```

Что касается онлайн компиляторов, то там зачастую в качестве компилятора выступает gcc, который имеет нестандартное расширение, допускающее такое преобразование.

А проблема с `strcpy` вызвана настройками проекта. VC++ по-умолчанию ругается на все "недостаточно безопасные" функции из C, хотя такой код полностью соответствует стандарту. Для исправления достаточно последовать совету, изложенному в сообщении об ошибке.

Comment: @БорисЛебедев Дополнил ответ про `strcpy`

Comment: Я благодарю вас за стремление помочь мой проблеме. Действительно, ваше решение  помогло, однако, помогло лишь отчасти: ошибка под пунктом 2 осталось, вследствие чего скомпилировать проект без ошибок не получается. Возможно, есть альтернативное решение? Еще один вопрос, который я хотел бы задать: раз Вы говорите, что код является не рабочим, то почему он компилируется в онлайн-компиляторах без ошибок, например, https://ideone.com/UF7aE7. Неужели автор книги мог привести неверный код?

Comment: @БорисЛебедев Про онлайн компиляторы в ответе тоже написано

Comment: @БорисЛебедев кстати, список онлайн-компиляторов Вы можете найти в [описании метки c++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2b%2b/info)

Answer (score 4):

Книга была написана давно, тогда, когда в языке С++ действовали стандарты C++98 или С++03, в которых разрешалось преобразование строковых литералов к типу `char *`. Но даже там оно являлось deprecated, и за его использование всяким Лафоре следовало бы давать по рукам.

Это преобразование было навсегда удалено из языка в стандарте С++11.

Поэтому чтобы компилировать код из этой книги вам придется использовать компилятор, работающий в режиме C++03 или ранее (или переводить современный компилятор в этот режим).

В Visual Studio 2017 нет полноценного ключа, переводящего компилятор в режим C++98 или C++03. Но разрешить требуемое устаревшее  преобразование можно либо огульно, переведя настройку проекта `C/C++:Language:Conformance Mode` в положение `No`, либо более целенаправленно, указав в командной строке компилятора настройку `/Zc:strictStrings-`.

Comment: Совет отключить Conformance Mode не особо хорош, ведь при этом сломается многое другое.

Comment: Перевод современных компиляторов в старый режим работает с [некоторыми нюансами](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53412721/3240681).

Comment: @älёxölüt: В чем смысл этого конкретного "нюанса" по ссылке мне не ясно. В до-С++11 языке нет и не могло быть никакого `<random>` и пытаться включать его смысла нет. Так что это не нюанс совсем, а просто автор, не понимающий, что творит.

Comment: О том и речь, что clang должен был завернуть этот код, а не сожрать.